# How does Oracle SELECT FROM dual work with multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's the structure of a query I came across:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE t
USING (SELECT ? id, ? email, ? cr_date, ? info, ? status FROM dual) n
ON t.id=n.id and t.email=n.email
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET z.info = n.info z.status='Y'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (info, status) VALUES (n.info, n.status)
```

I've read up on using DUAL to return SYSDATE or other operations... is the SELECT simply returning some input values into a table (row) to simplify further operations in the other clauses?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you came across is meant to update a single row, or create it if it doesn't exist.

DUAL is a special system table containing just one row. 
Selecting from DUAL is a workaround for Oracles inability to do simply:

```
select sysdate;
```

Note that it doesn't have to be `dual`, it can be any one-row-table or even a query that returns one row.

```
select sysdate
  from dual;
```

is equivalent to:

```
select sysdate
  from my_one_row_table;
```

and

```
select sysdate
  from my_table
 where my_primary_key = 1;
```

Since version 10g, the `dual` table has a special access path which shows up in the execution plan as "fast dual", which results in 0 consistent gets, which isn't possible to achive on your own using other tables.

Comment: Actually, the SQL '92 standard requires a FROM clause. To say DUAL is "a workaround ... for Oracle's inability" is a bit misleading. It is the "select sysdate" that is a non-standard shorthand. DUAL is a table that contains one row, and always exists in Oracle databases. Ref: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: Why do I need a call to dual then? Is it more efficient than passing in the bound variables directly?

Comment: You need the call to dual because the MERGE statement *requires* a valid query in the USING clause.

Comment: @DCookie, I argue it would be infinitely better if Oracle implemented the shorthand like other dbms vendors, regardless of whether it is in the standard or not.

Comment: I would agree it would be a nice feature, however, to fault a vendor for standards compliance is wrong. It really doesn't take that much from my productivity to add the extra 10 characters to my select statements.

Answer (score 0):

a) Yes you can use like this statement. But you must rename your "date" field name cause its keyword of oracle.
b) but i stongly recommend to create procedure for this.

Answer (score 0):

Read about DUAL table : http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Dual 
It commonly used for SYSDATE, Can be used for multiple fields such as below too:
    SELECT USER, sysdate from dual;

Answer (score 0):

The statement appears to be doing essentially an Update Else Insert using a little trick with DUAL. The "?" appear to be bind variables.

The same logic could look like (in pseudocode):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.id= ?,
    t.email= ?,
    t.status= 'Y'
```

IF update updated 0 rows THEN

```
INSERT into t
VALUES (?, ?)
```

where the two ? are the "info" and "status" variables respectively.

Using DUAL just reduces your work into one database call instead of two.